# Access to the resource is forbidden - Connect Microsoft Planner using Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get a list of tasks from Planner in Power BI.  I am getting data using From Web with this link: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tasks?$filter=createdBy eq 'me'

I will sign in with my organizational account, press connect but then I get a message stating "Access to the resource is forbidden".

Is it possible to get a list of planner tasks from Power BI?  If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.